# How are methods of class Walker_Nav_Menu invoked?

Tags: menus

The class has a method called start_el which runs displaying the menu items without invoking it. Don't you have to invoke it like so:

```
$example = new Walker_nav_menu();
$example -> start_el(args...);
```

The class is instantiated in a nav menu function call,

```
wp_nav_menu(
   array(
                'menu'            => $menu_id,
                'container'       => 'div',
                'container_class' => 'wp-megamenu-main-wrapper '.$dynamicclass,
                'container_id'    => 'wpmm-wrap-' .$menu_location,
                'menu_class'      => 'wpmegamenu',
                'menu_id'         => 'wpmega-menu-' . $sanitized_location,
                'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
                'before'          => '',
                'after'           => '',
                'link_before'     => '',
                'link_after'      => '',
                'items_wrap'      => '<ul' . $attributes . '>%3$s</ul><div class="wpmega-responsive-closebtn" id="close-'.$menu_location.'">'.$submenus_retractor_text.'</div>',
                'depth'           => 0,
                'walker'          => new WPMegamenuWalker_Class()
            )
);
```

How does the code inside start_el function run without invoking this method? What am I missing here?

Comment: It gets [invoked here](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/6.0.1/wp-includes/class-wp-walker.php#L146). (Found by searching WP for `->start_el`, only this one occurrence found)

Answer (score 0):

In short, `wp_nav_menu()` calls upon the [`walk_nav_menu_tree()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/walk_nav_menu_tree/) function and passes along the processed arguments (including the [`Walker_Nav_Menu`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/walker_nav_menu/) instance to use, if provided).

`walk_nav_menu_tree()` invokes the the `Walker_Nav_Menu::walk()` method on the provided instance or on a new instance of the default `Walker_Nav_Menu` class if none was provided.

`Walker_Nav_Menu::walk()` iterates through nav menu items and contextually calls other relevant methods on the instance as necessary in order to convert the items to markup. In the case of `Walker_Nav_Menu::start_el()`, whenever beginning to construct the markup for an item.

`Walker_Nav_Menu` inherits it's `walk()` method from the plain ol `Walker` class - see [`Walker::walk()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/walker/walk/).